# Vue - altering model arrays

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple Vue template consisting of an object with two arrays (dummy/placeholders vs actual data).

```
data() {
  var tableColumns = new Array();
  tableColumns.push({"dummyValues": ["date 1", "date 2"], "csvValues": []});

  var variables = {
    "tableColumns": tableColumns
  };

  return variables;
}
```

---

```
<td v-for="(item, key, index) in tableColumns">
    <span v-if="item.csvValues.length == 0" v-for="dummyValue in item.dummyValues">
       {{dummyValue}} <br />
    </span>
    <span v-else v-for="value in item.csvValues">
      {{value}} <br />
    </span>

</td>
```

At first, I only have dummy values. Something happens along the way (I parse a CSV file) and I need to exchange the dummy data I've first rendered with actual values. 
I thus append my real data to the real data array (`csvValues`) and hope the `v-else` will take care of it.

This doesn't work - why, is my approach wrong?

Comment: Try using [`Vue.set`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)

Comment: Your syntax/use of the data part seems strange, don't define logic here. Define tableColumns as follows tableColomns: [], next move the 'push' part to a method, and call it for example on mounted.

Comment: @M.Suurland there's no logic in my data() method, it returns a plain array. The problem isn't with showing the initial data, but rather modifying the model afterwards - the changes aren't reflected. I can inspect the data when debugging with Chrome or the Vue extension, the new elements are there, but they're not rendered. I just get "undefined" for each of them.

Comment: This seems a issue regarding reactivity, see: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Not sure you understand my issue - I'm not trying to render "non-reactive" properties - they're both "reactive", they're declared up front. 

_Switching_ between them doesn't work. Whatever *if* branch I first render, that's the one I need to keep rendering, otherwise I just get a number of "undefined" values equal to the number of elements in the first rendered list (even though the IF should evaluate to false and execute the ELSE branch).

Comment: Are you actually returning an array from your data method? Vue won't allow that. It will even throw a warning in in the console, "data functions should return an object".

Comment: @BertEvans: no, I'm returning an object that wraps this array and more stuff. I overly simplified it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Vue can't switch between two data sources (dummyValues and csvValues). 
I had to use a third one, which now holds/cycles elements from either of the first two. So, instead of building my view from one or the other arrays, I'm popping/pushing stuff to my third array (renderingValues) and always iterating that one.

Want to render `dummyValues`?
- pop everything (previously `csvValues`) from `renderingValues`
- push everything from `dummyValues` to `renderingValues`
- iterate `renderingValues`